# Issue while downloading in file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to download a file using requests. I am running it on python 3.6.5. Below is my code:

```
import requests 
file_url = "http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/db-book/db4/slide-dir/ch1-2.pdf"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream = True) 

with open("python.pdf","wb") as pdf: 
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk: 
            pdf.write(chunk)
```

Getting the below error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='codex.cs.yale.edu', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /avi/db-book/db4/slide-dir/ch1-2.pdf (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000001421CF5080>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

I have tried a number of suggested methods on the same issues like increasing the timeout but it doesn't help. Also, that link is working perfectly fine.

Any idea on whats wrong here?

Comment: It works fine for me. Check you connection too.

Comment: @Akhilesh Connection is fine ..i am able to open that link with the browser

Comment: Can you try wget or curl command on the pdf, to check if you can actually download the pdf

Comment: Beware, it is common to declare proxies inside the browser, while by default Python uses no proxy...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I checked i couldn't find any proxy defined. Its automatically detect settings. Any way to find the exact issue?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I am not aware of the exact command for that. I will check and try.

Comment: Works fine for me. They've probably blacklisted you because of too many attempts.

Comment: One thing i am using a remote terminal with spyder IDE installed on it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using looking into fake user agents e.g https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/ and using proxy rotation to hit the endpoint you are trying to hit.
A good example on how to achieve those is https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the remote terminal. 
Somehow the remote terminal won't execute the connections and it might throw an error. It worked fine on my personal machine.

Thanks all for your suggestions.